# iPhone 6(s) plus not scaling new application correctly for some users

Tags: uiimageview, storyboard, xcode7, scaling, launcher

I have a brand new Swift 2.0 XCode 7 Storyboard based application.
Target is set to 9.2. I'm currently supporting any device with GPS that can run ios 9.2

I started with the Tabbed View Template and I'm working in wAny and hAny and a single Storyboard.

It works fine in the simulator on a bunch of phones, both orientations and works fine on my 6s plus, 6s, 6 plus and a 5.

But for some users the scaling is wrong and everything comes out squished.
Even in landscape mode the TabBar Icons are very close to each other.
Narrower than even on my 6s plus in portrait.

I believe this is caused by my application not having a Launch bitmap.

My understanding is there are two ways to implement this.
Launcher .XIB/.NIB with half a dozen specific sized bitmaps attached. Or a StoryBoard Launcher with ... exactly what.

The "Or StoryBoard" is a little vague. But I wanted to keep things using the modern approach since this app is new and targeted users tend to have the latest device.

So I created my Launch Image set and tried to attached it to the UIImageView in the Launcher StoryBoard. It won't list items that are tagged as "Launcher Image Set". It will show other Image Sets and Icons. But not the ones specifically for Launcher. It shows an "L" in the xcassets list next to the Launcher Image set. I believe I have the build project setting set correctly and it looks perfect on many of the same exact devices.

After some digging, I read that if you use the "StoryBoard" method you don't need the 6 or so bitmaps anymore. You can put anything in the Storyboard Launcher View and treat it just like you would treat your main storyboard.

So I did that. I just centered a small image.png file in the View of the Launchers Storyboard. Works on all simulations and my iPhone 6s plus. I did not pin it to the edges because that would mess up the aspect ratio of the image.

A very small set of users still have the issue and one of them even uninstalled and reinstalled.

I tried playing with setting phone Zoomed, Normal, Text Size, Bold etc. They all work. Users also don't have anything out of the ordinary on these system settings.

So first, do I need the 6 proper sized bitmaps or not? I read conflicting info on this.
If I want to use the 6 images on a storyboard how to I get them in the UIImageView of the Launcher StoryBoard if they won't list? Should I put them in a regular image set. Does the "Launcher Image Set" only work for the for the Launcher.XIB?

If it's not the Launcher window, what else could it be causing this?

I know I could create a XIB/NIB with the 6 bitmaps. But that seems like I'm going backwards and I don't care about old OS versions or older phones.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer. When using a Storyboard Launcher you cannot use a "Launch Image Set" for your Launcher Storyboard. You have to use an Image Set.

This is the best Video I found that covers it A-Z.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vz6tCgXgZFo

It also didn't fix my initial problem. Which I'll post separately. It scales correct in Portrait but not in Landscape for hand full of users. Using the same hardware as others that it works fine on.